# Array.pop - last two elements - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

I have a question using Array.pop function in JavaScript. Array.pop removes and returns the last element of an Array. My question is then: is it possible to remove and return the last **TWO** elements of array and return them instead of the last?

I am using this function to return the last element of URL, like this:

> URL: www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1

```
'url'.splice("/").pop(); -----> "handcreamproduct1"
```

**what i want is:**

```
'url'.splice("/").pop(); -----> "cream/handcreamproduct1"
```

I want to take the last two parameters in the url and return them, with .pop i only get the last one. Remember that the URL is dynamic length.  The url can look like this:

> URL: www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1
>   **OR**
>   
>   URL: www.example.com/products/handcream/cream/handcreamproduct1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the array, use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the last two elements, and then [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with slashes:

```js
var url = 'www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1';

var lastTWo = url
  .split("/") // split to an array
  .slice(-2) // take the two last elements
  .join('/') // join back to a string;

console.log(lastTWo);
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks @Ori, had a feeling that slice would be a better option.

Comment: id like this easy way

Comment: @Asim - in this case splice would work as well. You need to split first, however :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in array function to do that.

Instead use

```
const urlParts = 'url'.split('/');
return urlParts[urlParts.length - 2] + "/" + urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
```

Comment: I think that the answer of @Ori is more clean way with joining. You are doing the same almost but difference is you print out the parts and .join is a built in function

Comment: I have run a quick performance comparison and my solution is 5 times faster.

In Node v7.5.0:
array slice: 525.144ms
array index: 103.884ms

(for 10000x)

Comment: So much difference? even that slice is a built-in function?

Comment: Yes I have written a blog post about that a while ago now. http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/05/Get-the-last-element-of-an-Array-in-JavaScript/ Anyways if performance is not an issue for you, the more readable solution might be more attractive

Comment: I hope you aren't testing this on `'url'` as a string rather than `url` as a variable containing a long string with slashes to split on. `'url'.split('/')` will return `['url']`.

Comment: No I didnt -__-. I used the string from the accepted answer `var url = 'www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1';
` for both tests

Answer (score 1):

I love the new array methods like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter.) so there is a [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tpbf14u9/) with using this

```
let o = 'www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1'.split('/').filter(function(elm, i, arr){
    if(i>arr.length-3){
  return elm;
  }
});
console.log(o);
```

Comment: Nice, i looked at the demo looks promising. But i need to return string not array. Thanks anyway, learned a new function today :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[^/]+\/[^/]+$/` to match one or more characters that are followed by `"/"` followed by one or more characters that are followed by end of string

```js
let url = "https://www.example.com/products/handcream/cream/handcreamproduct1";

let [res] = url.match(/[^/]+\/[^/]+$/);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This returns "/" slash before the first element. "/cream/" instead of "cream/". And using regEx is not the clean way of doing this or does this have a benefit over the rest?

Comment: @Asim _"This returns "/" slash before the first element."_ See updated post, removed `\/` from beginning og `RegExp`. _"And using regEx is not the clean way of doing this"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, now it works :)! Well the accepted post has a much cleaner way of reading the code. regEx is not easy to understand for a human eye. (im a beginner). This question was made to help my problem but also help me and other understand more.

Comment: @Asim Not certain what "clean" means. _"regEx is not easy to understand for a human eye. (im a beginner). This question was made to help my problem but also help me and other understand more."_ No endeavor is guaranteed to be "easy"

Comment: "clean" --> "readable". Yes true that but always a good thing with multiple options of answers. Just a quick question how is regEx compared to slice and splice with performance?

Comment: @Asim _""clean" --> "readable""_ That is still not an unambiguous definition of "clean". "readable" is subjective as well; whether a text, symbol or glyph is "readable" depends on the viewers' decision and effort to comprehend what is being "read". "Performance" requires comparison of different approaches as to usage of time and resources. You would need to perform benchmarks on the different approaches to determine the actual results.

Comment: So what you mean is that regEx can be more "readable" for some people that other? but using characters from alphabet can be hard for some people also? seriously? Reading the word "splice" is hard for some people than reading this "/[^/]+\/[^/]+$/" ?

Comment: @Asim You mentioned "understand more" in a previous comment, and "easy" and "easier". Understanding any field of endeavor is not "easy". Not certain what "some people" consider hard or easy. Nor does it matter. "some people" claimed to have deciphered the hieroglyphics of Ancient Egypt in 4 years, though the rites required 30 years to even be considered for invitation into the understanding of the glyphs, et al. "some people" are still trying to understand the glyphs, "some people" claim they have deciphered the glyphs today; though they have not, as it is not possible. JavaScript is different

Comment: You did not answer my question do you still think there are some people think that "split" should be much harder to read than "/[^/]+\/[^/]+$/". Simple question. There is possibilities to use Malbolge instead of regex also, there are 10000 possibilities what i am saying in 10000 methods there are some easy and some hard to understand. @Ori's explanation was much easier than this regex code to understand for ME not people happy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156819/discussion-between-asim-and-guest271314).

Comment: @Asim It is your Question. Did not and am not not questioning your selection of an Answer. Cannot be certain what someone else thinks. Can only evaluate actual conduct.  The concepts of hard and easy are relative.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the URL string has a trailing / then the answers here would only return the last part of the URL:

```js
var url = 'www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1/';

var lastTWo = url
  .split("/") // split to an array
  .slice(-2) // take the two last elements
  .join('/') // join back to a string;

console.log(lastTWo);
```

To fix this, we simply remove the trailing `/`:

```js
const urlRaw = 'www.example.com/products/cream/handcreamproduct1/';
const url = urlRaw.endsWith("/") ? urlRaw.slice(0, -1) : urlRaw
const lastTWo = url
  .split("/") // split to an array
  .slice(-2) // take the two last elements
  .join('/') // join back to a string;

console.log(lastTWo);
```